# PrimeFaces inputText ajax event=valueChange fires AFTER commandButton clicked

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

Using JSF and PrimeFaces 6.1 I have an inputText field as such:

```html
<p:inputText value="#{backingBean.stringField}">
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="@form" />
</p:inputText>
```

and within the same form is a commandButton:

```html
<p:commandButton id="btnDoThatThing" 
                 ajax="true" 
                 immediate="true"
                 update="@form"
                 process="@this"
                 action="#{backingBean.doThatThing}"/>
```

When I

1. make a change to the inputText field,
2. then click somewhere OTHER THAN the command button
3. click the command button

everything works exactly as expected. BUT if I:

1. make a change to the inputText field,
2. immediately the command button

The button is NOT fired since the first click of the commandButton is triggering the valueChange event to happen in the inputText field.

If I click it a second time the button action finally happens.

Now, if i change the `p:ajax event="valueChange"` to `p:ajax event="keyup"` the first click of the commandButton work as expected, but unfortunately the keyup event on a inputField is pretty hacky and you lose  functionality within the field (copy/paste text, text selection, 'fast' typing' etc)

Any thoughts on how to initiate the change event in the inputText field, AND fire the commandButton action when the user clicks the button immediately from typing in the inputText field?

Comment: what about the "blur" event?

Comment: unfortunately 'blur' has similar issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First your `valueChange` is triggered. This updates the form **including** the button. Not 100% sure if this is browser dependent, but in Chromium (Linux), the click on the previously rendered button (before it has been updated) is not executed.

I could get it working when I changed the update expression into a [selector](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/selector.xhtml). My expression updates the elements I needed to be updated **excluding** the button(s). In my case:

```html
<p:ajax update="@(form :input:not(button))" />
```

Note that the `change` event is default for inputs, so I've removed `event="valueChange"`.

Of course you do not need to use a selector. You can also just update a component (like a panel) which does not contain the button:

```html
<p:ajax update="yourPanel" />
```

Also, `ajax="true"` is default for a `p:commandButton`, so you can remove that.

Comment: **Thank You @jasper-de-vries !** This works perfectly, and doesn't even feel like a hacky workaround (like some other ideas I was attempting). This post is going at the top of my bookmarks for future reference :)

Comment: not really working for me, I'm updating only an outputLabel using it's  id in the ajax update still a click on the button fores the change event only @jasper-de-vries

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved the same problem removing the following statement from my page (Primefaces 11.0):

<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()"/>

Somehow the onstart event overrides the click event and only one event is processed: change.