# PrimeFaces p:ajax event=change and p:commandButton action

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am having some trouble with my application. I have a `<p:inputText>` with a `<p:ajax>` listener for the change event. I also have a `<p:commandButton>` on my page. Both the ajax listener and `<p:commandButton>` work as expected when only attempting to invoke one. The problem occurs when user edits `<p:inputText>` and while still focused on the field, attempts to press the `<p:commandButton>` which triggers the change event ajax listener (expected) but the `<p:commandButton>` is not invoked (not expected).

Here is my code:

```
<p:inputText id="code" 
             value="#{myBean.code}" >
    <p:ajax event="change" 
            listener="#{myBean.method1(myBean.code)}"
            update="@(form :input:not(button))" />
</p:inputText>

<p:commandButton id="searchButton" 
                 value="Click me"
                 action="#{myBean.method2(myBean.code)}"
                 process="@this code" 
                 update="@form"
                 oncomplete="PF('myDlg').show()" />
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749194/primefaces-inputtext-ajax-event-valuechange-fires-after-commandbutton-clicked) question but the answer didn't seem to solve the issue for me.

I have tried processing the button on the ajax listener and I tried putting the button in a different form and not updating that form from the ajax listener but I can't figure it out. Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Tried using `blur` instead of `change`?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, the same issue happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is running on JSF 2.2 runtime, you can utilize passthrough attributes from namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough`

I had the same issue (button doesnt work on 1st press, on next presses it works) and solved it on following way:

1. Add namespace to your page

   ```
   xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
   ```
2. Add `oninput` attribute to `p:inputText` (no need for `p:ajax`)

   ```
   <p:inputText id="code" value="#{myBean.code}" pt:oninput="onTextChanged()"/>
   ```
3. Add `p:remoteCommand` bellow

   ```
   <p:remoteCommand delay="300" name="onTextChanged"
                    actionListener="#{myBean.method1(myBean.code)}"
                    update="@(form :input:not(button))" />
   ```

(Delay is not necessary but it gives better performance if text is typed fast.)

`oninput` attribute will help your input fields to detect any kind of change event: typing, deleting, copying, pasting, cutting,etc... and via `p:remoteCommand` to pass them to managed bean.

And you will also solve "button" issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english.

I found another workaround for this issue.
Advantage against approved answer - no additional requests to server on user input.

I realized that the problem is that the button onclick handler is not called.
But I noticed that the onmousedown handler is called. So I added an onmousedown handler where I shedule onclick call. In the onclick handler I check if the method has already been called or not. And if it was, I cancel the event. So onclick executes only one time for one button click.

Page markup:

```
<p:commandButton id="searchButton"
                 ...
                 onclick="return fixOnclick(event)"
                 onmousedown="return fixOnmousedown(event)"
</p:commandButton>
```

Javascript:

```
fixOnmousedown: function (e) {
    const target = $(e.target);
    target.data("eventToProcess", null);

    setTimeout(function () {
        target.trigger("click");
    }, 10);

    return true;
}

fixOnclick: function (e) {
    const target = $(e.target);

    if (target.data("eventToProcess") == null) {
        target.data("eventToProcess", e);
    }

    return target.data("eventToProcess") === e;
}
```